# how to send https/http request with network credentials in go

Tags: go, https, beego, networkcredentials

in c#

```html
var uri = new Uri("https://demo.com/");
                var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                request.Method = "POST";

                request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(utility.commonkey, utility.commonsecrerkey);
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                request.Accept = "application/vnd.demo+json;version=3;";
                request.ContentLength = encoding.GetByteCount(json);
                request.Headers.Add("data", json);
                HttpWebResponse response = null;
```

and in go i can add only add these

```html
req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
 req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic sdfsfscefewfewfew")
 req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/vnd.demo+json; version=3;")
```

here in go the challenge is how to add network credentials in go

Comment: So what is the problem you're having? As long as the `sdfsfscefewfewfew` corresponds to `user:password` in base64, this should work fine.

Comment: need to add  request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(utility.commonkey, utility.commonsecrerkey); also but not sure how to do it in go

Comment: @Havelock, in which parameter of request i should be adding this network credentials....please refer above c# code...

Comment: What is represented with `utility.commonkey` and `utility.commonsecrerkey`? Is it username and password?

Comment: these keys are basically...keys by which server decides which api to serve

Comment: When I looked at [the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) I see only username and password...

Comment: a kind of username and password then we can treat??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see in [the C# docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx) what you're referring at as keys, could only be username and password. You could use the analogue `http.Request`'s [method](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.SetBasicAuth) to set username and password for basic auth.

```
// username has the same value as utility.commonkey
// password is the corresponding password in plain text
req.SetBasicAuth(username, password);
```

Don't forget to remove the following line from your Go code as well

```
req.Header.Set("Authorization", "Basic sdfsfscefewfewfew")
```

Comment: yes it is true...its actually username and password kind of